# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_8 is incompatible with the layer: using tf.keras 2 CNNs to concatenate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I am trying to concatenate 2 CNNs. This is the Code:

```py
        input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(64,64,1), name="camera")

        input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(64,64,1), name="lidar")
        

        #  First branch

        input1_features = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0)(input1)

        input1_features = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(4, 4), padding = 'same', activation='relu')(input1_features)

        input1_features = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding = 'same' ,activation='relu')(input1_features)

        input1_features = keras.layers.Flatten()(input1_features)



        # Second branch

        input2_features = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0)(input2)

        input2_features = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(4, 4), padding = 'same', activation='relu')(input2_features)

        input2_features = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding = 'same' ,activation='relu')(input2_features)

        input2_features = keras.layers.Flatten()(input2_features)




        merged = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1_features, input2_features])

        hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)

        hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(hidden1)

        output = keras.layers.Dense(action_space, activation='softmax', name="action")(hidden2)

        nn = keras.models.Model([input1, input2], output)
        nn.compile(loss={"camera" : "mse",
                         "lidar" : "mse"},
                          optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4096 but received input with shape [32, 512]

This is the code for predict :

```py
np.argmax(dqn.predict([camera,lidar]))
```

I've already double checked the shapes of both images and they are (64,64,1).

I am trying to write a a nn that gets 2 images as inputs and outputs one of 9 actions.

I already tried to play with all the parameters in Dense but I got nothing. Here is the summary of the model :

[summary model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8vwt.png)

Comment: What version of Keras do you have? I just ran your code on Keras 2.3.0-tf and got no errors?

Comment: I am using 2.3.0-tf. I am trying to check maybe is something wrong with my images..

Comment: Are you getting the error when you compile or fit? I only tested on .compile.

Comment: I just checked the image that I am generating and it is ok. Grayscaled, shape(64,64,1).

Comment: I just noticed you have defined Softmax that makes your model a classifier. Apparently you are trying to classify 9 actions. I think there is a problem with how you have defined your loss. You need to define your loss as 'categorical_crossentropy'. If I am wrong please elaborate more what you mean by {"camera" : "mse","lidar" : "mse"} as a loss value.

Comment: Yes, you are right . I defined it as sparse_categorical_crossentropy as my actions are integers. But the error is still there.

Comment: The error shows up when I try to predict (code is posted). I did not fit my model and I don't know if that is the problem or not. I try to use this model as a nn for a DDQN. When the online network tries to predict this error is thrown. So I tried to predict 2 images from scratch with the model. What I observed is that if I eliminate the Flatten layers it works But that is wrong because I should use them.. I think it's related to that.

Comment: Try reshaping your 2 input images to (1, 64, 64 , 1) before predicting. image = image.reshape((1, 64, 64 , 1)). That should fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, it worked. But can you explain me why ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Basically it is because we train the model on batch of images so it expects (batch_size, 64, 64, 1) as an input. When predicting on a single image we have to add that additional dimension which indicates predicting on single image of size (64,64,1). Would appreciate if you up vote if the problem was solved!